# CGContext draw with two UIColor with opacity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cgcontext

I am drawing a line using CGContext and color has transparency of 0.7 , Now i want to draw another line with another color with same transparency on that previous line . But i get the second line color as a solid color without any transparency in the part where this both two lines intersect. For first line i am using blend effect clear to draw a transparent line and for the second line i am using blend effect color. Please tell me how to draw these two lines separately so that the second line drawn can have its own separate color .

Answer (score 2):

The default blending mode (`kCGBlendModeNormal`) should provide the behavior you want in both cases.